GEE Error: Unable to transform edge
This Google Earth Engine (GEE) code is designed to extract daily Land Surface Temperature (LST) data from MODIS and compute the average LST for each county in the United States during the growing season (March to November) from 2008 to 2023. The code performs the following tasks: 1.Extracts MODIS LST Data. 2.Crop Mask Application. 3.Daily LST Calculation and Export.
link
/**
 * Extract MODIS LST (daily) for each county in the US
 */


/**
 * Convert a collection to an image with each band representing an image
 * in previous collection
 */
var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBand));
  
};

// Function to transform EVI collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // create band name as sensor_DOY if the band has properties DOY and sensor
  // otherwise, band name as system:index
  var bandName = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.List(current.propertyNames()).contains('bandname'),
                                  current.get('bandname'),
                                  current.get('system:index'));
  // var bandName = current.get('system:index');
  // rename the band
  current = ee.Image(current).select([0],[bandName]);
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(current));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
}


/**
 * Function to add "DOY" as bandname
 */ 
var addBandname = function(img) {
    var datestring = ee.String(img.get('system:index'));
    var format = 'YYYY_MM_dd';
    var eedate = ee.Date.parse(format, datestring);
    var doy = eedate.getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);
    var year = eedate.get('year');
    var bandname = ee.String(year).cat('_').cat(doy);
    return img.set('bandname',bandname);
};

/**
 * Function to import LST
 */ 
function stackLST(start,end,region,mask,mode) {
  // mode: 'Day' or 'Night'
  var band = 'LST_' + mode + '_1km';
  var qcband = 'QC_' + mode;
  var coll;
  if(start.substring(0,4) == '2001' | start.substring(0,4) == '2002') {
    // coll = 'MODIS/006/MOD11A1';
    coll = 'MODIS/061/MOD11A1';
  } else {
    // coll = 'MODIS/006/MYD11A1';
    coll = 'MODIS/061/MYD11A1';
  }
  var LST = ee.ImageCollection(coll)
              .filterDate(start,end)
              .filterBounds(region)
              // .map(function(img) {return img.updateMask(img.select(qcband).eq(0))})
              .map(function(img) {return img.updateMask(img.select(qcband))})
              .map(function(img) {return img.select(band).float().multiply(0.02).updateMask(mask)})
              .map(addBandname)
              .sort('DOY',true);
  
  // print(start,end,region,LST);            
  var LSTstack = stackCollection(LST);
  // var LSTstack = comp.stackCollection(LST);

  return LSTstack;
}

/**
 * Export
 */
var exportTable = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table.select([".*"], null, false),
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'Data_county',  //*********
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};



// get only counties with corn and soy
// var counties = UScounties16;
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties');
// Map.addLayer(counties, {}, 'ctn');

var start = '-03-01';  //*********
var end = '-11-30';   //*********
// var end = '-08-30';   

// loop through each year ***************
for(var i = 2008; i <= 2023; i++) {

  var year = i.toString();
  // var p_year = (i-1).toString();
  // get crop mask
  var cropMask;
  if(i>2006)
  {
    //cropMask = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/'+year + '_01_01').select('LC_Type1').eq(12);
    var start_day = year + '-01-01'
    var end_day = year + '-11-30'
    // var start_day = '2023-01-01'
    // var end_day = '2023-12-31'
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_day, end_day))
                  .first();
    cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1); // 1- corn, 5 - soybean

    
  }
  else{
    
    // var mcdband = 'MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    var mcdband = 'MODIS/061/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    cropMask = ee.Image(mcdband).select('LC_Type1').clip(counties).eq(12);
  }
  
  // get LST day stack
  var LSTday_stack = stackLST(year+start, year+end, counties, cropMask, 'Day');
  // print(LSTday_stack.limit(10));

  var meanLSTday = LSTday_stack.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);
  exportTable(meanLSTday, 'LSTday_daily_mean_' + year);
  
  // get LST night stack
  var LSTnight_stack = stackLST(year+start, year+end, counties, cropMask, 'Night');
  var meanLSTnight = LSTnight_stack.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);
  
  exportTable(meanLSTnight, 'LSTnight_daily_mean_' + year);

}


I got this error:
Error: Unable to transform edge (21503.000000, 5932.000000 to 21503.007828, 5932.000000) from SR-ORG:6974 PLANAR [499.9999999997749, 0.0, -2.0015109355797E7, 0.0, -500.000000000225, 1.0007554677903E7] to EPSG:4326. (Error code: 3)
Six months ago, I was able to run this code and export the CSV to Google Drive, but today I tried running it again and encountered an error. I'm not sure what's the problem. I've searched all the related questions, most of which are about "clip" and "reduceRegions" functions. But I find there is no error. Could you please help me?
